# Where can I buy a Bianchi Pista Concept?

Tags: maintenance, tire, commuter, performance, fixed-gear

I would like to buy a Bianchi Pista Concept 2005...2009 like this one:

http://velospace.org/node/24912

Where can I find this bike in London, UK? And what should I check before buy it?

Also, How much should I expect to pay for?

Thank you.

Comment: As was suggested in [this meta question](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/107?tab=votes#tab-top), regional questions may get more answers if they're opened up to broader geographic areas.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer, but [the Bianchi dealer locater shows several dealers in London](http://www.bianchi.com/global/dealerlocator/dealerlocator_list.aspx?SearchCountry=United%20Kingdom&SearchZone=London). I'd call around and find out what the ballpark is in terms of cost.